# Como faço para que meu app seja listado pelo botão de inserir do WhatsApp

Tags: android, android-intent, whatsapp

Eu preciso que meu app apareça na lista de apps com sons para compartilhar, qd a gente clica naquele clips do `WhatsApp`, sabe aquele botão do `whatsApp` para inserir uma imagem, um som, etc... como na imagem abaixo[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui] eu estava usando para isso o seguinte `intent-filter`

```
<intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <data android:mimeType="audio/*"/>
</intent-filter>
```

esse `intent-filter` faz meu app aparecer em outras listas, menos na do `WhatsApp`.

Por ex, quando tem algum som (fora do meu app) e eu clico em compartilhar esse som, meu app é listado como opção... Porem qd eu clico no clips do `whatsApp` para add um som ele não é. Isso me deixou na dúvida, estou fazendo a coisa certa? Pq eu não quero que meu app receba nenhum som, mas sim informe ao `WhatsApp` que ele tem sons para ser compartilhado...

Alguém pode me ajudar? Alguém sabe o que eu preciso fazer? Eu sou nova nisso e realmente preciso que meu app aparece na lista de possibilidades do WhatsApp...

**Nota** - qd eu clico em algum som de dentro do meu app ele consegue ser compartilhado normalmente via WhatsApp, o unico problema é que ele não é listado nesse bendito botão de clips...

Não sei se consegui me expressar bem (como disse sou nova nisso), se alguem não entender o que quero fazer, me fala que edito a questão :)

Valeu!

Answer (score 0):

Tente isso...

```
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.GET_CONTENT" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.OPENABLE" />
  <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: Obrigada Gabriel, mas não rolou :( Tentei usar só o seu `intent-filter` e tb add ele ao que já tinha, porem o app ainda não é listado...